# How to avoid select from drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know how to avoid select text listed when I am populating drop down at run time.

```
    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    row["cabTypeId"] = "0";
    row["cabType"] = "Select";
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
    ddlCabSize.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["cabType"].ToString();
    ddlCabSize.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["cabTypeId"].ToString();
    ddlCabSize.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    ddlCabSize.DataBind();
```

If i will select drop down list means "select" should not show to dropdownlist. Help me that how to do it?

Comment: dude... i read your question 3 times...you have to do better than this... forget about the english but give us more details...where did you put this code? is it in a event ?

Comment: separate function. i am calling that function in page load event.

Comment: So let me get this right: You have a dropdown list and "Select" is the first one showing up. Then you want nothing to happen when the user chooses "Select" , but only when the other options are chosen?

Comment: kindly understand my requirement. i am having one dropdown which is used to list out available cab(car). i have added "select" programmatically before, while i bind data from database with dropdown. because whenever page is load drop down should show "select". thats what i have added "select". but when i am selecting the dropdown, "select" appear with available cabs.

Comment: So you have a list of cabs and you just want to add a first item that says "Select" on top of the list of cabs?

Comment: @vetriJith So let me get this straight: what you want to do is, have "Select" remove from the list when the user clicks on the dropdown ?

Comment: yes. you are 100% right. what i have to do? for this...

Answer (score 0):

For the need on insert, you can add this code bu using `Add Method`

```
ddlCabSize.DataBind();
ddlCabSize.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select .."));
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/e7s6873c.aspx

Note : You can also use Insert Method

You must add Columns to your tables

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn ("Name", Type);
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
```

So :

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn ("cabType", typeof(string));
```

Comment: kindly understand my requirement. i am having one dropdown which is used to list out available cab(car). i have added "select" programmatically before, while i bind data from database with dropdown. because whenever page is load drop down should show "select". thats what i have added "select". but when i am selecting the dropdown, "select" appear with available cabs.it is main problem.

Comment: VetriJith, you can add this code:  ddlCabSize.DataBind();
ddlCabSize.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select .."));

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
ddlCabSize.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ddlCabSize.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["cabType"].ToString();
ddlCabSize.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["cabTypeId"].ToString();
ddlCabSize.DataBind();
ddlCabSize.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Below","0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking.

Try swapping your values around.

```
ddlCabSize.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["cabTypeId"].ToString();
ddlCabSize.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["cabType"].ToString();
```

Comment: kindly understand my requirement. i am having one dropdown which is used to list out available cab(car). i have added "select" programmatically before, while i bind data from database with dropdown. because whenever page is load drop down should show "select". thats what i have added "select". but when i am selecting the dropdown, "select" appear with available cabs

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question correctly, you want t remove the item with the text "Select" or value = "0" from the dropdown list once the selection is changed

You can use jquery to do this very easily, for that you need to know the clientId of your dropdown list which is very easy to get using the [ddlCabSize.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property

add jquery reference to your page like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

and copy the script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#<#= ddlCabSize.ClientID #>").change(function () {
         $("#<#= ddlCabSize.ClientID #> option[value='0']").remove();
     });
 });
</script>
```

See the [fiddle for more info](http://jsfiddle.net/kJZRa/4/)

Comment: you are 100% right, about what i am expecting. i tried with your code. but it does not work. tell me how to do it?

Comment: i fixed it check again, the value that you are passing is string, i'm checking for int, that is why it is not working, try copying the code again, may be now it will help

Comment: you need to add jquery reference to your file, for this to work, let me know if you need help

Comment: yes. still it is not working. could you tell me how to  add reference with my applicaiton?

Comment: try now, it must work, but you may want to change the reference to your local hosting, download [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) and add it to your scripts folder and change the reference link to your local copy

Comment: at what name along with extension i have to save?

Comment: you can save it with any name the extension can be .js, jquery is nothing but a javascript library, it is a bunch of javascript functions, learn about it, it will be very helpfull

Comment: hello dude, i tried, even i am working with local host only.but it is ot working if you are willing to attend via team viewer means , i will give details. could you able?

Comment: hi vamsi, could you tell me an idea about this problem> i thing we conored the problem.

Comment: Update your question with the complete code related to the question, post both aspx and aspx.cs code in the question so that i can help you fix it, you can remove everything that is not related